# How does Multiattack work in Mutants and Masterminds 3rd Edition?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-3e

I am currently learning the DC Adventures RPG which is based on Mutants and Masterminds 3rd edition. I have both and the multiattack wording is the exact same for each game.

> Multiattack: "A multiattack effect allows you to hit multiple targets, or a single target multiple times, in the same standard action." pg 148 of the M&M3 core rule book.

Does that mean you can attack the same person a number of times equal to your rank? Example: multiattack 5 would grant 5 attack rolls against 1 target. And on the other hand with multiattack 5 you could hit up to 5 separate targets with in range?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Multi attack isn't ranked.  Rather, an attack gets the Multiattack property, which increases the attack's power point cost by +1 for each rank of the attack.

It has three options:

- You can attack a number of people in an arc, with a lowered attack bonus against each
- You can deal extra damage to one opponent (assuming your attack can damage them) based on how much you beat their Defense by
- You can provide 'covering fire' to give all ranged attacks a penalty against one character. Attackers can ignore this penalty at the expense of giving you a free attack against them.

See [the d20Hero SRD's 'Modifiers' page](http://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/modifiers) for more details.

**Single Attack:**

> To use a Multiattack against a single target, make your attack check
>   normally. If successful, increase the attack’s resistance check DC by
>   +2 for two degrees of success, and +5 for three or more. This circumstance bonus does not count against power level limits.
>        If an Impervious Resistance would ignore the attack before any increase in the DC, then the attack still has no effect as usual; a
>   volley of multiple shots is no more likely to penetrate Impervious
>   Resistance than just one.

**Multiple Attacks**

> You can use Multiattack to hit multiple targets at once by “walking”
>   or “spraying” the Multiattack across an arc. Roll one attack check per
>   target in the arc. You suffer a penalty to each check equal to the
>   total number of targets. So making a Multiattack against five targets
>   is a –5 penalty to each attack check. If you miss one target, you may
>   still attempt to hit the others.

**Covering Fire**

> A Multiattack can provide cover for an ally. Take a standard action
>   and choose an ally in your line of sight, who receives the benefits of
>   cover against enemies in your line of sight and in range of your
>   Multiattack. (You have to be able to shoot at them to get them to keep
>   their heads down or this maneuver won’t work.) You cannot lay down a
>   covering attack for an ally in close combat. An opponent can choose to
>   ignore the cover provided by your covering attack at the cost of being
>   automatically attacked by it; make a normal attack check to hit that
>   opponent.

Comment: So for a single target attack you make attack and get those bonuses, and the actual number of times your hero punches the villain is just up to your description of the attack? ie multiattack 5 in a power is just +5 to the attack roll and not 5 separate attacks?

Comment: @MC_Hambone: It's not even a +5 to the attack roll... It's your normal attack bonus for that attack, rolled once, and then a bonus of either +2 or +5 for exceeding the target's defense.

Comment: @MC_Hambone - you don't have 'Multiattack 5', you have a Blast 5 Multiattach.  It costs 3pp/rank (Damage @ 1pp/rank, ranged +1pp/rank, multiattack +1pp/rank) and you describe it as 'multiple laser blasts'.  You attack your opponent and can deal extra damage if you exceed their defense by the appropriate amounts.  Multiattack does not increase your attack roll, ever.